# Arbuh mayoys viesreem (420) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

Every number in the Torah is special, as is widely known z especially as related in the "echad mi yodeya" song

It's known that the second temple stood for 420 years, but can any other significance of the number 420 be found in the Torah?

Blessings and success

Comment: How is it possible for any bawley chaweem to even think about contemplating the concept of the idea of the theory to even start to begin the thought of downvoting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Melachim I 9:28](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.9.28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> וַיָּבֹ֣אוּ אוֹפִ֔ירָה **וַיִּקְח֤וּ מִשָּׁם֙ זָהָ֔ב אַרְבַּע־מֵא֥וֹת וְעֶשְׂרִ֖ים כִּכָּ֑ר** וַיָּבִ֖אוּ אֶל־הַמֶּ֥לֶךְ שְׁלֹמֹֽה׃ (פ)

They came to Ophir; there **they obtained gold in the amount of four hundred and twenty talents**, which they delivered to King Solomon.